# Can I pass the result of an xslt template as a param to another template?

Tags: xslt

I am trying to basically recreate the functionality of an ASP.NET master page with an XSLT template.

I have a "master page" template that contains much of the page html stored in an .xslt file. I have another .xslt file specific to a single page, that takes in xml representing the page data. I want to call the master page template from my new template, and still have the ability to insert my own xml that will be applied. If I could pass a param that would allow me to call template with the param as the name, that would do the trick, but that doesn't appear to be allowed.

Basically I have this:

```
<xsl:template name="MainMasterPage">
  <xsl:with-param name="Content1"/>
  <html>
    <!-- bunch of stuff here -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$Content1"/>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

And this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="MainMasterPage">
    <xsl:with-param name="Content1">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>More Content</p>
      <xsl:call-template name="SomeOtherTemplate"/>
     </xsl:with-param>
   </xsl-call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

What happens is that the nested xml is basically stripped and all that is inserted is "TitleMore Content"

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for explanation of the issue and for a correct solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The problem with the provided code is here:**

> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="$Content1"/>
> ```

This will output either the concatenation of all text-nodes descendents of the top node of `$Content1` (if it contains a document) or the string value of its first element or text child (if it is an XML fragment).

**You need to use**

`<xsl:copy-of select='$pContent1'>`

**instead of**

`<xsl:value-of select='$pContent1'>`.

This correctly copies all children nodes of `$pContent1`

**Below is a corrected transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="MainMasterPage">
    <xsl:with-param name="pContent1">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>More Content</p>
      <xsl:call-template name="SomeOtherTemplate"/>
     </xsl:with-param>
   </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="MainMasterPage">
  <xsl:param name="pContent1"/>
  <html>
    <!-- bunch of stuff here -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="$pContent1"/>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="SomeOtherTemplate">
   <h2>Hello, World!</h2>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <p>More Content</p>
   <h2>Hello, World!</h2>
</html>
```

Comment: +1, good answer. Is it possible to, instead of `copy-of`, use `apply-templates` (with the same `select`), to apply templates to intermediate results? I've been trying to get this to work for a while now, and it doesn't complain, but the result is simply empty.

Comment: @roe: Yes, but apply-templates is equivalent to copy-of only when the templates to be applied are equivalent to the identity transform.

Comment: I get that, my problem is that I'm trying to perform a transformation, and then another transformation on top of that result (one transformation modifies the text-content, inserting zero-width space characters, and the second transform does the markup, e.g. fo-inline blocks), but the result is empty for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I have answered several questions with examples how to implement multi-pass processing in XSLT -- should be easy to find. To do this in XSLT 1.0 generally requires the use of the `xxx:node-set()` extension function.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it working. Thanks for the `node-set` pointer too, without it as keyword, it was definitely not easy to find.. :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Do you know if passed params have a maximum size, in terms of bytes, number of nodes, etc.? Thanks!

Comment: @snypelife, No, there are no such limits. None of the XSLT specifications defines any such limits.